# Can't run Zend Framework 2 on a server - Class 'Zend\Mvc\Application' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I can't run ZF2 on server. Every time I got this error:

> Class `'Zend\Mvc\Application'` not found in /home/.../public/index.php on line 12.

In apache logs:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Class `'Zend\\Mvc\\Application'` not found in /home/.../index.php on line 12.

I've tried to change permissions of `ZF2_PATH` with no results. Path is correct. Maybe that's something with `mod_fcgid`?

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It's not a permissions problem or the error would be "permission denied".  Is the framework actually installed where you think it's isntalled?

Comment: Well the problem is resolved now. It wasn't problem with the framework but with php 5.4. I don't know exactly where the problem was because update php to the newest version 5.4.x series solved the problem. But it's some kind of problem with escape_seq. So my first trace was correct. Anyway thanks for reply

Comment: @5k7 can you put it as an answer and accept it so it's not in "unanswered" anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly where the problem was because update php to the newest version 5.4.x series solved the problem. But it's some kind of problem with escape_seq.